Alter page title with tokens for a search_api view page
In my Drupal 10 installation, with views, search_api, search_api_solr I have a view which search in solr.

I want my search page to have the title "You searched for {{ keywords }}".
I cannot get tokens to work in the title field, tried with various tokens.
I have also tried with the following hook_preprocess_HOOK.
function ab_base_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
  if ('view.searchapi.page_1' === \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()) {
    $keywords = \Drupal::request()->query->get('query');
    if ($keywords) {
      // Yes we do get in here.
      $variables['#title'] = t('Search results for: @query', ['@query' => $keywords]);
    }
  } 
}

No matter what, the page title doesn't change for what i set in the view title.
